# GKE Cluster Autoscaler pre creates nodes on time base

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud. Master version is 1.8.9-gke.1, nodes versions are the same, cluster autoscaler is enabled.

I started to notice that nodes are being created without any pending pods. Those nodes can then sit without running pods for 20-30 minutes, then workload will be allocated to them. This is usually happening before peak hours and looks like cluster is trying to predict load base on load in the past.

Is it something that Google Cloud Cluster Autoscaler managing or is it Kubernetes feature? Is it configurable? I was trying to find any clue in the documentation, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something the Cluster Autoscaler would do.

Go to Stackdriver Logging and query with advanced filter:

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="<your_cluster_name>"
resource.labels.location="<your_cluster_zone>"
protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update"
```

(The last line alone might suffice). I think this should be the way to get the autoscaler logs. If this does not work, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I found logs where autoscaler requests new node, but there is no explanation why it's requesting them as there is no pending pods are scheduled.